# du displaying old results

Tags: ubuntu, bash, du

I ran `du -hs` to find out how big my `/home/user` directory was and it reported as 18G. I cleared out almost 4G of data and ran `du -hs` again to find out how much space I actually saved and it still reports as 18G. `--apparent-size` makes it report as 19G. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you "clear out" the filesystem by unlinking files that were in use at the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files are still in use, `du` will not update.

Here's a [post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/freebsd-why-command-df-and-du-reports-different-output.html) with an exercise so you can see this in action : (for BSD, but it's equivalent in Linux)

Comment: df will do this but I don't think that du will follow this behavior.

Comment: Goodness!  What does this user have running to hold 4GB of files open?  Wow!  That's a lot of wedged zombies.  (Ewww, mental image...)

Comment: @lornix: a DVD image perhaps, that was being played with VLC, mplayer etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility that can cause this is filesystem compression and utilities that don't know about it.  I saw this with ZFS a few years ago on Solaris but the theory should be the same for Ubuntu and any other filesystem that supports compression.

I created a file with `mkfile 10g test`.  After this, `ls -lh` reported it as 10GB and `du -h` reported it as 0.

If the 4GB you cleared out was found with `ls -lh` then it might not have been taking up nearly as much space as it seemed.

Comment: Something similar can also happen with *sparse files*. `dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=10G seek=1 count=0` creates a file that `ls -lh` reports as having 10GBs.

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by *hard links* which means that the files you deleted still exist under other names. To find them, run `find -type f -links +1`.